# iOS 16 WidgetKit Lock Screen Animated GIFs

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, ios16

Starting with iOS 16, it's possible to display animated GIFs on the Lock Screen using WidgetKit.

Some Apps that currently support this feature:

- https://apps.apple.com/app/id1527221228
- https://apps.apple.com/app/id1641107226

I've tried it myself with the following code:

```
struct AnimatedGIFWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var gif : UIImage {
        
        UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test2", withExtension: "gif")!))!

    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: gif)
    }
}
```

but that only shows the first frame of the GIF.

Am I missing something?

I've created a sample project: https://github.com/guidev/AnimatedGIF

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Looking to do something similar.

Answer (score -1):

What makes you think UIImage support dynamic gif? It only support the static gif, just like what you got. You need to created your own timer to update the SwiftUI.Image.

You will need some deeper framework like "Image I/O", to get the frame rate of the dynamic gif and use that to create your timer and update the image yourself.